# Pybars does not compile jinja if condition and for loop

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I am using saleor platform on a project. Im trying the compile emails having jinja templates syntax using pybars. But the pybars is not parsing the if condition and the for loop syntax. Please guide me on parsing this two.

Thanks!

```
context = {
    "site_name": "site_name",
    "order": {
        "items": [
            "one",
            "two",
            "three",
        ]
    },
}

source = """
    {% if True %}
        <div>
            {{ site_name}}
        </div>
    {% endif %}


    <div>
        {% for line in order.items %}
        <tr>
            {{ line }}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <div>

        <p><small>This email was sent to <a href="mailto:{{site_name}}">{{site_name}}</a>.</p>

    </div>

"""


from pybars import Compiler
compiler = Compiler()


template = compiler.compile(source)
template(context)
```

Output that i am getting is as below.

```
'\n    {% if True %}\n        <div>\n            site_name\n        </div>\n    {% endif %}\n\n\n    <div>\n        {% for line in order.items %}\n        <tr>\n            \n        </tr>\n        {% endfor %}\n    </div>\n\n    <div>\n\n        <p><small>This email was sent to <a href="mailto:site_name">site_name</a>.</p>\n\n    </div>\n\n'
```

Comment: pybars does *not* render the Django template languge, it only renders pybars directives: https://github.com/wbond/pybars3#handlebarsjs-compatibility So what changes is for example that `{{site_name}}` in the `mailto:...` clause is rendered as `site_name` itself, which likely is not the intention.

Answer (score 0):

> But the `pybars` is not parsing the if condition and the for loop syntax. Please guide me on parsing this two.

That makes sense since pybars is not something that renders Jinja syntax. It handles pybars syntax. The [GitHub repository](https://github.com/wbond/pybars3#handlebarsjs-compatibility) lists a set of features of that language.

You can render this with the Jinja template engine with:

```
from jinja2 import Template

Template(source).render(context)
```

Your template should also use `{% for line in order.items() %}` so with a method call, otherwise you will iterate over a method, and this will raise an error.

For the given template, this will look like:

```
    <div>
        site_name
    </div>



<div>
    
    <tr>
        ('items', ['one', 'two', 'three'])
    </tr>
    
</div>

<div>

    <p><small>This email was sent to <a href="mailto:site_name">site_name</a>.</p>

</div>
```